# JMockit incompatableClassChangeError when using NonStrictExpectations result =

Tags: exception, junit, jmockit

Ok I am having this issue at work where I am using JMockit 1.19 and trying to use NonStrictExpectations to make a method throw an exception. However I keep getting this "IncompatableClassChangeError." I'm not allowed to share my exact code at work but I have recreated the problem with example code below that is giving me the same issue

Class Being Tested

```
public class TestClassRemove {

    A a = new A();

    public String testMethod(){

        String s = null;

        try{
            s = a.getA();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("caught exception");
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Class A whose method is called by TestClassRemove

```
public class A {

    public String getA(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Test Class where Im having the problem

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TestingTests {

    private TestClassRemove testClassRemove = new TestClassRemove();

    @Mocked
    A a;

    @Test (expected=Exception.class)
    public void testResultsEqual(){

        new NonStrictExpectations(){{
            a.getA();
            result = new Exception(); //This throws "IncompatableClassChangeError"
        }};

        testClassRemove.testMethod();
    }
}
```

for some reason the line " result = new Exception(); " is throwing this  "IncompatableClassChangeError." Any ideas????????

Sorry for the poorly named classes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I FINALLY solved this issue after almost a week of working on this and asking everyone in the office. I had linked another project on my build path and that's what caused this issue. Not only did it affect this but this prevented eclEmma from working as well as Mockito. Linking projects on your build path will cause TONS of errors using JMockit, Mockito, and eclEmma.